# How to update multiple columns on duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of radiobuttons that are inserted into a database in an array.  This works fine the first time through.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` ) VALUES ";
        foreach ($params AS $key => $value) {       
            if (( $key != "form_key" ) && ( $key != "stylecolor" ) && ( $key != "key" )){           
                $values[] = "('$sku', '$key', '$value', NOW()) ";       
                }
            }
        $query .= implode(', ', $values) . ';';
```

I am trying to get it to update these columns when the state of the radio button is changed so changing this :

```
$values[] = "('$sku', '$key', '$value', NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = '$value'";
```

It will work and update if there is only one radio button in the array selected with this query:

```
 INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` )
 VALUES ('1893240720', '1', 'no', NOW()) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 'yes';
```

however when I have multiple buttons selected it breaks the query :

```
INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` )
VALUES ('1893300667', '1', 'yes', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 'no',
('1893300667', '2', 'yes', NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 'maybe';
```

Do I have to have separate `INSERT` or how do I check for duplicates and then update each `value` of its respective `note_id` ?  Is this just a case of bad syntax?

### edit

from the answers so far it seems I was not clear that I need to be able to update multiple values at once.  I dont understand how I can have the `ON DUPLICATE` at the end if I need to update multiple values with different variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zac, yes you can perform this action by specifying the statement once (at the end):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` ) VALUES ";

foreach ($params AS $key => $value) {       
    if (( $key != "form_key" ) && ( $key != "stylecolor" ) && ( $key != "key" )){           
        $values[] = "('$sku', '$key', '$value', NOW()) ";       
    }
}
$query .= implode(', ', $values) . 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);';
```

See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This doesnt make sense to me, I need to be able to update multiple values, 1 might become a no and 2 might become a maybe.  Know what i mean?  So that update value would have to be set accordingly and maybe different for each `note_id`

Comment: Zac, this is still correct. Using the VALUES function acts a pointer to the `value` column within each VALUES set contained within the parenthesis. Therefore it will be dynamic, and reflective of the value being inserted.

Comment: Oh I think I got it! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

If your primary key is note_id, then

```
INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` )
VALUES ('1893300667', '1', 'yes', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`value` = 'no',
style_color = VALUES(style_color),
created_at = VALUES(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you only specify the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE once. Like this..

```
INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `style_color`, `note_id`, `value`, `created_at` ) 
VALUES ('1893300667', '1', 'yes', NOW()), 
       ('1893300667', '2', 'yes', NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(`value`);
```

EDIT: Forgot the first NOW(), which I've added.
EDIT: Added Value Function to pull in value of column.

It's been awhile since I've done this, but I believe this is the case.

Comment: Note, this only works when your update value is the same for all inserts. In your case, they were both 'no'.

Comment: No they will not be the same for all the inserts, sorry I did not make that clear.  It looks from all the answers that was the assumption.

Comment: Don't forget that your update value can if necessary be computed using the inserted (via `VALUES()`) and/or existing values.

Comment: @Neil, nice I had forgotten this. Thanks. +1